# Want to add Arrow for Subcategory under Dropdown

Tags: css, joomla

I am designing a website in Joomla.

I want to add arrows on the drop down categories like When we select Gender: (here I want to add down arrow) shows a drop down like: Men/Women and here i want to insert a right direction arrow.

I have following options as I am working on Joomla:

```
Link Title Attribute:
Link CSS Style
Link Image:
```

Now problem is when I insert image then it is not fitting a the position where I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Position Absolute to the Image Element and Fit it to any position:

E.g :

```
.arrow {
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px; /* position as per your element */
     left: 30px; /* position as per your element */
}
```

Comment: can you show me your website link ? or Html css on fiddle . 
I will write you proper css code .

Comment: Like i have the following options :                                                                                   <a href="http://imgur.com/GPHqCQ3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GPHqCQ3.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: Here is the website link:  http://www.hispindia.org/         I want to add it under the Resources for Publications and Useful Links:

Comment: OK what you can do here : 
Give a class to the li
.item-484 a:after{
     content: " ";
     width: 30px; /* give width / height as per icon */
     height: 30px;  /* give width / height as per icon */
     background: url('../images/arrow.png');
     position: absolute; 
     top: 10px;
     right: 5px;
}